# Shrink material faces in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Iam using Threejs for rendering model in browser, after rendering model in browser is it  possible to shrink the faces, not the mesh. Give your suggestions for it.

Comment: can anyone give your suggestions regarding my question.

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_subdivision.html)? I am not sure this demo is working correctly, however...

Comment: check this link. http://i40.tinypic.com/2hg62w2.jpg. This, the thing I'am trying to do...

Comment: Look at `three.js/examples/js/modifiers/ExplodeModifier.js`. Once each face has its own unique vertices, you can move each face to a new location.

Comment: yes, i modified the vertices value by own calculation, but i doesn't see any changes on the model, do i need to create material and mesh again after changing the vertices value.

Comment: Now that I understand your question, I have provided an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See

```
three.js/examples/js/modifiers/ExplodeModifier.js.
```

Once each face has its own unique vertices, you can move each face vertex to a new location. You will likely also want the reset the face `centroid`, `faceNormal`, and `vertexNormal`s.

If you are using `WebGLrenderer`, you will have to set

```
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

See the Wiki article [How to Update Things with WebGLRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates).

Comment: Thanks, Langley.. It works great by geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true. can you give a clear cut idea on using the explodemodifier.js

Comment: If you are having additional problems, please make a new post, show your code or a live example, and ask a specific question. Thank you.